# uppercase form textfield

Tags: 8, forms

I want to have a form textfield automatically uppercase the text entered as it is typed in.  I was hoping that there was as set-able property that would allow for this but I’m unable to find one.

> $form['elementName'] = array(
>             '#type' => 'textfield',
>             '#title' => $this->t('Address'),...
>   )

The searches I have done so far point to the use of  ‘Plugins.’  However if there is a simple(er) solution I prefer that.  Any ideas appreciated;

Comment: Is there any reason why you did not try a JS solution? "change case as you type" is pretty much a JS use case.

Comment: yeah, it's pretty much obvious that it would best be done by js.  I was just hoping that there might be a textfield 'property' that drupal would recognize and build the js to perform this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However if there is a simple(er) solution I prefer that.

Sorry, maybe I going too deep, but the most simpler solution that you can use just for display is a CSS solution.

Based in your example:

```
input[name='elementName'] {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

That's it, any char will be uppercase in your textfield. If need store in uppercase, just change case before save.

Comment: if the text in the field is in UPPERCASE why wouldn't it be stored that way when submitted?

Comment: @Mike Simple, the text only display UPPERCASE, its value not in uppercase. If you check the value of your input you will see that is exactly way that was typed (if typed with caps, 'A' or 'a' otherwise).

Comment: Vagner, You are absolutely correct; the submitted value is as it was typed.  While I want both -- submitted and typed to be uppercased -- you answered the question as asked.  It also showed me something new and interesting.

Comment: @Mike, if you creating a class that implements FormInterface just use `submitForm` function to get the values and use `strtoupper` php function to change case and then you can store. This is was talking in 'just change case before save'. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution would be to do this in a submit handler before the value is actually saved.

If this is for display purpose - the Drupal way is to not alter what is saved, but alter how it appear on screen.

Comment: it is for display; thus the hope for property js solution.